# How to create teams in firebase crashlytics after migration from fabric?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have migrated from fabric to firebase by connecting apps via console but I am not getting crash report emails from firebase. I added different users from "Users and Permissions" as suggested [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/index.html#teams). But I am still not getting email notifications on crash. I tried creating custom role from google cloud console but I am not able to see that in my firebase console. Only case where I am getting mails is when I am adding new user as "Owner" which I think is not right because it would mean I should give full access to all team members. Has anyone faced such issue before?

P.S.: Crashes are logged in console but I am not getting email notifications on crash.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure your email preferences from Alert Settings under the alert icon on the top left of the console. What does this window look like in your firebase console?

[image]

2. Next you need to have at least view permissions on the project to receive e-mail notification. Project owners and editors get email alerts by default. More information on this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7276542?hl=en).

Comment: I did this but I am still not getting emails

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/crashlytics-integration/email-notifier

Comment: That is node.js code. I am  a frontend android developer. I don't think such simple migration would be so hectic

Comment: Did you try adding the user as an editor instead of owner?

Comment: I haven't tried that but what's the point? I only want my user to see the crash not edit anything in it. Will try soon and let you know.

Comment: I agree that you want the principle of least privilege. If editor works, try downscaling permissions. Probably you can find something here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions. Maybe the cloudnotifications.activities.list role is enough already!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208044/discussion-between-rushi-m-thakker-and-nebulastic).